# Having trouble loading JSON data from URL and displaying in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I am trying to create an HTML/JavaScript program that reads external JSON files (via URL), and then outputs them to the webpage in a nice listed order.

I have been working on this for days, and I can't seem to get past an error that pops up in the console of Internet Explorer. The error is:

### SEC7120: Origin (my azure webapp URL) not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. (my program name)

### SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.

I am able to read the first URL and read in the console via 'console.log(data)', but only because it is in the same origin domain as my code. Both are inside my Azure webapp git directory. How can I also via the other external JSON files from URLs? I have to read all of my classmates from their own webapps. Any help is greatly appreciated, I am really suffering here. I have a feeling that I need to use JSONp, therefore use the $.ajax() rather than $.getJSON().? I am using JQUERY. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Klump Test</h1>
<p><input onclick="AddStudent()" type="button" value="Add Student"/></p>

<script>
var urls = ["https://michael-pedzimaz-webapp.azurewebsites.net/my-information.json",
            "https://jakeisalsoclueless.azurewebsites.net/myinformation.json",
            "https://riotjuice.azurewebsites.net/my-information.json",
            "https://softwareengjmh.azurewebsites.net/format.JSON",
            "https://newtestdocument.azurewebsites.net/Format.json"];

function AddStudent(){
    var person = prompt("Please enter your json url:", "");
    //var _person = person + '?callback=?';
    getJson(person);
 }
</script>

<input onclick="getJson(urls[0])" type="button" value="Mike's JSON"/>
<input onclick="getJson(urls[1])" type="button" value="Jake's JSON"/>
<input onclick="getJson(urls[2])" type="button" value="Julian's JSON"/>
<input onclick="getJson(urls[3])" type="button" value="Jace's JSON"/>
<input onclick="getJson(urls[4])" type="button" value="Thad's JSON"/>

<div class="mypanel"></div>

<script>
function getJson(url){
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var info = 'First name: ${data.FirstName}<br> Last Name: ${data.LastName}<br> Preferred Name: ${data.PreferredName}<br> Team Name: ${data.TeamName}<br> Seat Location: ${data.SeatLocation}<br> Role: ${data.Role}<br>'

        $(".mypanel").html(info);
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How all of the JSON files are formatted:

```
{
"FirstName":"Michael",
"LastName":"Pedzimaz",
"PreferredName":"Mike",
"TeamName":"The Ocelots",
"SeatLocation":"1-2",
"Role":["UI Designer"]
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: search something about `CORS`,there will be lots of similiar question

Comment: CORS man bites newbies all the time

Comment: Is there a way to bypass the browser permission issue? Or is this a dead end and I am attempting to do the impossible.

Comment: @mpedzi03 dead end unless you control said API's your other option is to proxy these API's from your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with jsonp being what you need – however, the server you're requesting from needs to support jsonp in order to actually know about the ?callback URL parameter.

`azurewebsite.net` will need to support CORS (adding additional headers to let you to GET the JSON) or jsonp.

Comment: jsonp or json has nothing to do with a CORS issue.